# My code does not run in python idle

Tags: python

I am supposed to write a code to pay of credit card debts in an year or less where balance and annual interest rate are the inputs and the output is a monthly installment to pay off the debt in an year or less.The remaining math required for the upper bound and lower bound is in the code.Please help.

```
balance = int(raw_input())
annualInterestRate = float(raw_input())


lowestPayment = balance
monthlyPayment = 0
monthlyUnpaid = 0
temp = balance
monthlyInterest = 0

lowerBound = balance/12
upperBound = balance*((1+annualInterestRate/12.0)**12)/12.0
mid = 0

while  upperBound - lowerBound > 0.0000:
    mid = (upperBound + lowerBound)/2.0
    monthlyPayment = mid
    balance = temp
    for i in range(1,13):
        monthlyUnpaid = balance - monthlyPayment
        monthlyInterest = annualInterestRate/12.0 * monthlyUnpaid
        balance = monthlyUnpaid + monthlyInterest
    if int(balance) <= 0:
        upperBound = mid - 1
        if monthlyPayment < lowestPayment:
            lowestPayment = monthlyPayment
    elif int(balance) > 0:
        lowerBound = mid + 1


print 'Lowest Payment: '+str(round(lowestPayment,2))
```

Comment: I moved your code from your Pastebin link into your post body directly because it will make it easier for people to see and help. However, what is 'wrong' with your code?  What exactly are you trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: What precisely is the question that you're asking ?  Questions which appear to ask for help with homework in general terms are not encouraged.

Comment: i am supposed to use bisection search and find out a minimum monthly installment that needs to be paid in order to pay the debt in less than an year.math required:Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12.0
Monthly payment lower bound = Balance / 12
Monthly payment upper bound = (Balance x (1 + Monthly interest rate)^12) / 12.0